# NTFS filesystem partition detected as unknown on Linux after HDD cloning

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, ntfs, cloning

I have a problem with one of my partition.

I have cloned my HDD with a bigger one to have more space. Now Ubuntu is working perfectly but my second partition (/dev/sda4) which I know is a NTFS filesystem appears now as unknown filesystem in GParted. I try to mount the partition but I couldn't. I also tried :

sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt/ntfs
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.

I want to know if it's possible to specify the filesystem so the system knows that it's NTFS without formatting ?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT To answer all comments :

1. I take my hdd out and run it on windows 10 as an external drive. Windows is detecting the partition and its content and find no error with chkdsk.

2,3. It's possible to clone Windows I have made it with several computers but on this one I didn't install Windows on the hdd yet, I have just cloned my 500Go hdd with linux and the NTFS partition with an empty 1To hdd.

4. The cloning didn't fail.

Comment: I suggest running `chkdsk` on Windows. NTFS is a proprietary file system developed by Microsoft for Windows. Ubuntu has `ntfsfix` but it's generally a better idea to fix NTFS file system problems in Windows.

Comment: I seem to recall that Windows specifically ties the NTFS filesystem to the disk upon creation, to prevent this kind of thing. You're supposed to re-license and re-install Windows, according to Microsoft. After all, a system with a new disk is a new system.

Comment: Partition should not be an issue. But you cannot have duplicate UUIDs or then mount both clone & old drive when rebooting. Often issue is Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag. Then Linux NTFS driver will not normally mount, but can force mount in read only mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: To me it appears that the cloning operation failed - the cloned partition is not correctly recognized.